# Data visualization from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database, visualization

Im a newbie for such programming like reports/visualizations si I´m here just to ask for some advices, resources, tutorials..

The main goal of my new focus is to create custom charts/visualizations within really small time. Right now I have made some kinds of reports for Machines Overview, Machines Availability or OEE. These are made in MS SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services). This kind of reports creating is pretty good, also very limited and not modern. The procedures in SQL server are already written and at least everything I have to do is transform these data to a newer modern design (kinda innovative internal business project)

I started studying ASP.NET MVC 2 months ago to create these charts as a web app. Searched hours for tutorials and videos on youtube, but there are no proper tutorial to visualize data directly from database. Found chart templates for MVC e.g.:
link: https://canvasjs.com/asp-net-mvc-charts/stacked-column-chart/
Here I can find the main source code for the whole chart but the values that´s being showed are strongly typed. I´m trying to figure out how to show exact values from database. I would like to know how to assign exact values for axis X and Y + values calculated from stored procedure.

In visual studio followed the instructions from various tutorials how to create WebForms, MVC website etc. Everywhere they were showing local/strongly typed values.

I need 1 solution for reports where everything is prepared in SQL, there just needs to be somehow connected from database to chart.

Like in the mentioned link there is a controller window where should be maybe some {get; set;} statement from database with same column name as in SQL DB.

We are using 
SQL Server 2015
SQL Management studio 2015
SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)
MS ReportBuilder

the code to show can be expected in the mentioned link from canvas.js link for the whole MVC chart.

Reports:
I´m looking for a specific solution where I found specific charts (e.g.: canvas.js) what I have to edit and how, to use our data in specific charts. I´m interested in so bad because later in future my department will focus on creating custom specific charts for customer requirements.

Visualization:
Same goal as in Reports. Actually the visualization in production is just mentioned as "visualization" at least it´s just a report which has inside an html meta tag for 30sec autorefresh. I would like to know some other method where the data change could be asynchronous (I have heard something about React for this?)

Comment: Your question is likely to be off-topic and closed down because it's too broad, and also asking for recommendation is off-topic too (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But I would say, from your description, maybe look at PowerBI. Not sure you need to build a whole custom MVC app if you just want to directly link charts to SQL queries.

Comment: Sory, my fault if it´s off topic, surely looking for a solution where I build it up or edit existing charts by the customer requirements. PowerBI is good enough, I just dont know it´s freely editable or it´s limited just like ReportBuilder. Of course, the best way is to create charts as own, the invested time in it brings more value for sell

Comment: "I just dont know it´s freely editable"...in that case you can research it, but it's pretty powerful, you can do a lot more customisation than in SSRS. "the best way is to create charts as own"...not if someone else has made a product which already does everything you need.

Comment: if you insist on building your own, I would probably skip MVC and go for a solution with just HTML pages (with a framework like React/Angular/Vue to build the screens, plus your chart engine) and a Web API which just returns data. Unless you're planning to render a lot of HTML on the server side then MVC is not much use to you.

Comment: Our department focuses on projects where customer requirements are same or similar. Atleast every customer have their specific requirements and because if this we are looking for options or solutions where we will be able to create or edit every inch in the graphs/bars,charts if it will be needed. That´s why I´m looking for something like this. Will try that PowerBI too, thx.

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2015** version out there - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 -  so which one are you really using??

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is visualize data directly from database, you should look for a BI or business intelligence tool such as Power BI, SAS, SAP, etc.

If you plan to make them your own through a web app and you want to use ASP.NET MVC then you'd really have to study some Javascript, HTML, and MVC itself. What needs to happen is;

1. From your ASP.NET MVC web app, inside your Controller you need to get the data from the database. Search ADO.NET if you think Entity Framework might take some time.
2. Now that you have data in your Controller, it's time to pass them to the View. Search ViewBag or ViewData if don't want to use Strongly typed models.
3. Now that the data is inside the View, it's time to use Javascript or Jquery to loop through that data and pass them to the Charts javascript library you mentioned.

Comment: in html/css I´m quite good, in JS there are some things I should study, also to study the MVC itself. And thanks, will try to follow these steps. I can code with proper tutorials I can learn it really well and fast. Was just doing a survey that do I need to create a webservice for the data being catched by the controller in MVC. I have already made some tests with MVC like Showing a gridView from DB. But okay thank you. I was just wondering that am I on the right way to learn the technique to display data in chart.

Comment: I see, that's good that you're already familiar with those. Have fun, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

you can try dotnet Report builder https://www.dotnetreport.com and see if it works for your requirements. It’s very fast, installs with just a nuget package and some configuration. Sounds like exactly what you need. Full disclosure, I’m affiliated with the company.